# Issues passing values between views on ios with storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios

I have 2 UIViewControllers and I can pass values between them with no problem. The problem comes when I try to pass a value to a third view (a UITableViewController).
Here is my code

All the connections are set correctly, the tableview gets called here:

```
- (IBAction)goToTableView:(id)sender {
    TableMovieViewController *vc=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TableMovieViewController"];
    vc.finalResult.text=stringFromFirstView;
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

The `vc.finalResult.text` has by example `"Test Call"`, I verified and the value is there.

Now on the table view file:

.h file:

```
@property(strong, nonatomic)UITextField *finalResult;
```

.m file:

```
@synthesize finalResult;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UINavigationBar *nav = [[UINavigationBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 40)];
    UINavigationItem *navItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:finalResult];
    [nav pushNavigationItem:navItem animated:FALSE];
    [self.view addSubview:nav];
}
```

The `finalResult` never gets set with the value passed from the previous view.

Any ideas

Thanks
Rodrigo

Comment: tried but still the same, when I put the debugger on, the finalResult.text us blank something like this

    V finalResult = (UITextField *) 0X000000

Comment: You didn't allocate the UITextField mostlikely. Read the edit if you will. The other thing you can do is make a NSString property for the title of that UINavigationItem for testing purposes ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
UINavigationItem *navItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:finalResult];
```

With:

```
UINavigationItem *navItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:finalResult.text];
```

`finalResult` is of type `UITextField` and not `NSString`.
`initWithTitle:` asks for a `NSString` and not a `UITextField` as you are setting now.

EDIT:
As I read the edit that was meant as a comment on my answer you say that the `UITextField *finalResult` is a nil-value. This is probably because you did not allocate and ininitialise the UITextField as you should.

You need to do the `finalResult = [[UITextField alloc] init];` at least BEFORE the place you set the text of it. I suggest you do it in the init function of the `UITableViewController`.

Comment: Or if the UITextField finalResult is in the storyboard you should make sure that it is connected to it's outlet.

Comment: I considered that but in that case there would be a IBOutlet before the UITextField. Because he didn't say it in his example code I didn't deem it needed for the answer.

Comment: Yes, you're correct, but it is a possibility if he also forgot to add IBOutlet to the code. Either way, the problem is (most likely), as you said, that  `finalResult` is nil.

Comment: Sorry for posting on the wrong place. I did allocate the UItextfied on the init function as you mentioned and I put the IBOUtlet but it still not giving me any values. I see on the debugger that now is has been allocated but no value. There is any place I can send me project to you? it is really small, just trying to pass values between views. Thanks again

Comment: That shouldn't really be needed. You probably, as matsr said, haven't connected your UITextField to the storyboard. Try setting a default text value to the UITextField and see if that is working to the navigationItem.

Comment: Hey matsr, the finalResult is not placed on the storyboar, I just created it to get the value passed from the previous view to add as a title of the table view controller. It isn't on the storyboard

Comment: have you added the UITextField to the uitableview controller programmatically? (that was to be expected) but if it isn't used directly. Try and make a NSString property first and later the UITextField. U can eventually make the UITextField later.

Comment: Thanks Totumus, that did the trick. I am trying to set the question as answered but I am new and I don't know how to do it, can you tell me please.

Comment: press the checkmark beneath the upvote thingy ^^ you are welcome